# Why aren't these random gifs and colors working?

Tags: discord.js

So I tried to make a "hug" command where the gifs and the colors of the embed are random. The gif is not displaying and the color is always the same. Do you know how to fix it?

```
const erro = 'There was an error. Mention someone.'
```

```
const mentionee = msg.mentions.users.first()
```

```
if (msg.content.startsWith('+hug')) {
    const hugs = [
        'https://tenor.com/7Wko.gif',
        'https://tenor.com/QWw1.gif',
        'https://tenor.com/LUqw.gif',
        'https://tenor.com/beqF0.gif',
        'https://tenor.com/1jRF.gif',
        'https://tenor.com/xNZi.gif',
        'https://tenor.com/bpgad.gif',
        'https://tenor.com/Vl7g.gif',
        'https://tenor.com/u28I.gif',
        'https://tenor.com/2SQu.gif',
        'https://tenor.com/bbQCJ.gif',
        'https://tenor.com/TqvK.gif',
        'https://tenor.com/bfSJp.gif',
        'https://tenor.com/5QsA.gif'
        ]
        const gif = hugs[Math.floor(Math.random() * hugs.length)];
    const colors = [
        '#E27BFF',
        '#6F008E',
        '#AD00DD',
        '#650082',
        '#F6D7FF'
    ]
        const ton = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];   
    msg.channel.send(mentionee ? {
        embed: new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`${msg.author} hugged ${mentionee}!`)
            .setColor(ton)
            .setImage(gif)
    } : erro);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because of the  `msg.channel.send(mentionee ?` as the question mark is causing a problem.

Consider changing to the following(for discord.js v12 format):

```js
    msg.channel.send(mentionee, {
        embed: new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`${msg.author} hugged ${mentionee}!`)
            .setColor(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)])
            .setImage(hugs[Math.floor(Math.random() * hugs.length)])
    }).catch(error=> message.channel.send(erro));
```

I've changed the : erro into a .catch method so instead of crashing your whole entire process, it just catches the error and returns the default `erro` message.

I've also replaced the `mentionee ?` as `mentionee ,`, as this syntax has been confirmed to work.

Comment: Still. The gifs aren't loading and the color is always the same...

Comment: I've edited the code, also, maybe considering changing your tenor links as they show up as an error image, unsure how you fix tenor links doing that.

Comment: Yes, that must be the problem. The colors are already showing randomly and the gif link too, but they just appear as an error. I will search how to fix it thank you!

Comment: I've figured out a method where you click on the links and for each of them, right click the tenor image and then click copy image url address or something like that, should work afterwards!